# TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable - python,coldn't find out why?

Tags: python

this is my code, the purpose of the code is assume two integer and produce a list.start with a number, multiply its nonzero digits and add that product to the number. This is the new number in the sequence. Repeat.for example:Start with 12: multiply the digits (1*2) and add -> 14. Multiply its digits (1*4) and add -> 18, and so on.it will stop when it hit the limit(except the origin digit).`two integers 12,5(limit) and produce a list ['12','14','18','26','38','62']` i checked many times and i don't know why i get TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable. can someone trace for me? :)

```
def check_n(n,p,p1,old_t,new_t,fn1,t,limit):
    if len(new_t) - 1 != limit:
        if n != "":
            if int(n[0]) != 0:
                p = p*int(n[0])
                t = p + fn1
                return check_n(n[1:],p,p1,old_t,new_t,fn1,t,limit)
            else:
                return check_n(n[1:],p,p1,old_t,new_t,fn1,t,limit)
        else:
            pl = p1 + "," + str(t)
            old_t = str(fn1) + p1
            new_t = old_t.split(',')
            return check_n(t,p,p1,old_t,new_t,fn1,t,limit) 
    else:
        return new_t 
def in_both_sequences(n,limit):
    fn1 = n
    n = str(n)
    p = 1
    p1 = ""
    old_t = []
    new_t = []
    t = 0
    return check_n(n,p,p1,old_t,new_t,fn1,t,limit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the check_n function, n must be a string. But when check_n calls itself towards the bottom

```
return check_n(t,p,p1,old_t,new_t,fn1,t,limit)
```

you pass in t, which is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate the same error. But I tweaked the approach and this is gets the list you want

```
def check_n(base, limit):
    result_list = [str(base)]

    # Build the list to the limit
    for x in range(0, limit):

        # Pull the latest number
        str_base = result_list[len(result_list) - 1]

        # Multiply non-zero digits of the str_base
        prod = int(str_base[0])
        for y in range(1, len(str_base)):
            if int(str_base[y]) != 0:
                prod = prod * int(str_base[y])

        prod += int(str_base)

        result_list.append(str(prod))

    return result_list
```